# Quickbooks Process Request error = 80042500, There was an error when parsing the provided XML file

Tags: xml, quickbooks

Looking at the XML Validator tool I get the following response from trying to import my qbpos xml query into Quickbooks Enterprise.

Requested validation for QB POS (qbposxml), file has processing instruction indicating 
Reason: The element 'QBPOSXML' is used but not declared in the DTD/Schema.
Here is the start to the xml file, can anyone shine some light into what the problem is here? Using qbposfc3 for the AppendPurchaseOrderQueryRq() to create the xml response in C#.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1252"?>
<QBPOSXML>
  <QBPOSXMLMsgsRs>
    <PurchaseOrderQueryRs requestID="0" retCount="18" statusCode="0" statusMessage="Status OK" statusSeverity="Info">
      <PurchaseOrderRet>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you posted is the *response* XML. e.g. that's what you're supposed to get BACK from QuickBooks.

It is *not* what you are supposed to *send* to QuickBooks (e.g. the *request* XML).

Please refer to the documentation:

- https://developer-static.intuit.com/qbsdk-current/common/newosr/index.html

If you're trying to query for Purchase Orders, your request should look something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?qbxml version="3.0"?>
<QBPOSXML>
  <QBPOSXMLMsgsRq onError="stopOnError">
    <PurchaseOrderQueryRq>

...

    </PurchaseOrderQueryRq>
  </QBPOSXMLMsgsRq>
</QBPOSXML>
```

Comment: Is it possible to query the pos for information and import it into the QBE?

Comment: Yes, QuickBooks Enterprise has an API that's very similar.

Comment: So essentially get into the POS data, then manually create a response qbxml in the code based on the OSR guidelines or is there an easier way to go about this?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean. Can you rephrase your question? You shouldn't be building response qbXML at all. You should be building requests. You make requests, QuickBooks returns responses.

Comment: Yea I meant request not response.